# Arduino IDE error working with ESP8266 boards

Tags: c++, esp8266, arduino-ide

Just started working with arduino and esp8266.

I configured the Arduino IDE adding: http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json to preferences.
Installed esp8266 by ESP8266 Community version 3.1.1 from board manager
Selected Generic ESP8266 Module board for doing some tests
But when i click on "Verify" this error pops up:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'C:\Users\massi\AppData\local\Arduino15\preferences.txt'
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Generic ESP8266 Module.

I have no idea how to fix it
If anyone can help thanks

I tried reinstalling IDE and boards but still...

Comment: What happens if you run the following command in a terminal/prompt? `dir C:\Users\massi\AppData\local\Arduino15\preferences.txt`

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: It seems the IDE is looking for a file in a path that does not exist:

File "C:\Users\massi\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.1/tools/mkbuildoptglobals.py", line 485, in get_preferences_txt
    with open(file_fqfn, encoding="utf-8") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\massi\\AppData\\local\\Arduino15\\preferences.txt'
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Generic ESP8266 Module

Comment: I think you are in the right track... It seems you have to figure out from where it is trying to get this file. Probably you already have it in your system when installed Arduino IDE. Did you change the default installation directory when installing it? Sometimes these installers are broken and it's better to install everything in the default/suggested directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
Unistalled then installed from arduino original website.
Problem was downloading the app from the microsoft store, sometimes those apps are buggi or can generate some problems in the file system.